# Rotating a JLabel with a set icon (java)

Tags: java, image, rotation, icons, jlabel

I have a JLabel and I have set an icon to it. I want to rotate the label gradually (and the image set to the label) by clicking a button (I have implemented the KeyListener interface). Is there a such method or a way to do this. Here is some code:

```
lbTank.setBounds(width / 12 + width / 36 , height / 10 + height / 30, width / 36 , height / 30);
actionPanel.setLayout(null);
actionPanel.add(lbTank);
lbTank.setVisible(true);

tank = new ImageIcon(path to the file);
Image img = tank.getImage();
Image scaledImg = img.getScaledInstance(lbTank.getWidth(), lbTank.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
ImageIcon scaledBall = new ImageIcon(scaledImg);
lbTank.setIcon(scaledBall);
```

How to rotate the label (and the icon in it)?

...........................................

Comment: While there is a way, you are way better off using a single JPanel-subclass and overwrite it's paintComponent() method to render your full game instead of splitting your components into Swing classes. It makes your code easier to maintain and you get better preformance.

Answer (score 0):

'Rotating' a Swing Component will not work. The components are always rectangular with an upper left and lower right corner (position and size - there is no angle).

But when drawing the image you can apply some rotation, and you can ensure that the unneeded corners are transparent - giving a rotated impression to the user. It involves custom painting by overriding some component's [paintComponent()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)) method. In there find out at which coordinates and in which angle you want to paint, then create a matching [AffineTransform](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) and use this during painting in [drawImage()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,java.awt.geom.AffineTransform,java.awt.image.ImageObserver)).

This can be done in a generic way: Create a 'rotatable container', and any component you stick in there can be drawn in a rotated manner. If you do this with input controls (buttons, textfields etc) be aware that the rotatable container needs to also rotate mouse coordinates for this to work consistently.

Note that you override the paintComponent(Graphics g) method, but at runtime you will have to cast Graphics to Graphics2D so you can access all the needed methods.